# Hidding IP address during using torrent sites

Tags: security

If I download files from torrent websites using tor browser will my IP address be visible to others or not??
If yes then plz suggest me a way to hide my IP address so that I may be able to search anonymously. I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I prefer deluge BitTorrent Client to download torrent files.
thanks

Comment: Torrenting is off-topic here.

Comment: @ƎpᴉʇʎXD - I don't think torrenting *itself* is off topic, but using it for *illegal things* is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, your IP will be visible.** Furthermore, the default behavior of BitTorrent is that your computer becomes a seed for others to download from.

The only way to hide your IP would be to use a VPN or anonymizing proxy server. Although even with those measures, don't think you will be completely untraceable.

However, I will say no more since any pirating activities or off-topic here, and it seems like you want to hide your IP because you will be downloading things illegally. (Why else would you be torrenting? Unless it would be for a supposed speed increase, but I doubt that.)